# sed - replace several consecutive lines matching pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to replace two consecutive lines in a file with my text. For example:
**testfile.rb**

```
class Test
  def procedure
    nil
  end
end
```

I am trying to achieve this:
**testfile.rb**

```
class Test
  def procedure
    nil
  finish
finish
```

So I need to replace last 2 lines but this doesn't work:

```
sed -i 's/^\s\send\nend/  finish\nfinish/' testfile.rb
```

I understand that it fails because replacement is line by line. But how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '/end$/N;//s/end/finish/g' testfile.rb
```

Result

```
class Test
  def procedure
    nil
  finish
finish
```

- we want to look at a pair of lines only when they might both contain `end`, so 
  only read in second line when first line ends with `end`
- replace `end` with `finish`

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!  
Your last edit is shorter but harder to read for me. But also less flexible. Maybe leave both variants?

Comment: `sed -i '/end$/{N; s/end\nend/finish\nfinish/}' testfile.rb` works better for me

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\bend\s*\n\s*end$/finish\nfinish/ms' testfile.rb
```

This snippet works in multiline mode. `sed` is one line based by default.

Comment: Works perfectly but it's Perl not sed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
sed 'N;s/^  end\nend$/  finish\nfinish/;t;P;D' testfile.rb
```

With flexible indentation:

```
sed 'N;s/^\( *\)end\n\( *\)end$/\1finish\n\2finish/;t;P;D' testfile.rb
```

For even more flexible indentation, change spaces to `[[:space:]]`.