# How to search for files with a pattern of 2 consecutive new lines & modify the succeeding line?

Tags: grep, yaml

I have a few directories with a bunch of files that I need to change. That change involves me finding the files that includes the `selector` and `service` labels:

```
selector:
    service: XXXXX
```

and replacing the `service` label with `app`:

```
selector:
    app: XXXXX
```

Btw, none of the solutions in [this similar stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123102/sed-replace-several-consecutive-lines-matching-pattern) work.

Comment: Start with reading about sed, and here's a question that may help you get some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123102/sed-replace-several-consecutive-lines-matching-pattern

Comment: Since this is a YAML file, I suggest you read in the YAML into whatever language you're using, and then replace the element of the structure that you want to change.  Then, write out the new YAML based on your modifications.  In general, if you have structured data in a specific format, it's far safer and easier to read it, modify it, and rewrite it, rather than playing around with it as plain text.

Comment: @dcp I tried applying all of their answers and each of them threw an invalid command code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case You wanna AWK (gawk) solution. Here it is.
Considering input per Your question:

```
$ cat v1mg1rl.txt
application:
    id: 0
    service: WWWWW
selector:
    id: 1
    service: XXXXX
cartridge:
    id: 2
    service: ZZZZZ
```

AWK:

```
$ awk '/^[^ ]+/ { isselector=0; } /^selector:/ { isselector=1; } /^ +service: / { if (isselector) sub(/service: /,"app: "); } { print($0); }' v1mg1rl.txt
application:
    id: 0
    service: WWWWW
selector:
    id: 1
    app: XXXXX
cartridge:
    id: 2
    service: ZZZZZ
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate ya' Kubator! (Lol, nice name btw.)

Comment: Sure thing. Glad if helped.